# Can't connect to WiFi using Nougat

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, nexus

I updated to Nougat on my Nexus 5X. Can't seem to connect to some WiFi networks, as the connect button stays greyed out after entering credentials. What could be wrong?

[image: no dice]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that you should select at least one option in the "CA Certificate" field. I was able to save the setting after I set it to "Don't validate".

Comment: In Android 8 (Oreo) there's a big RED message saying "No certificate specified. Your connection won't be private." The best solution is to install a certificate in the Android system ( Oreo it's **Connections > Wi-FI > Advanced) Install network certificates**). Then the certificate will show up in the CA certificate menu and you don't have to choose Don't validate.